# Error org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Pais is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

Tengo 2 proyectos de Hibernate configurados exactamente iguales. Uno funciona y otro no, tambien misma librerias. Hay 2 paquetes uno configuracion y otro Clases (en los 2 proyectos estan igual pero en uno si va y en otro no)
Al darle a run hql y poner Fron Pais me da ese error.

```
Error org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Pais is not mapped
```

OS dejo la clases para ver si me hayais el problema.

CFG.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <mapping resource="Clases/Pais.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Clases/Continente.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

El reveng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="newmundo"/>
  <table-filter match-name="pais"/>
  <table-filter match-name="continente"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Hibernate Util

```
public class NewHibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;

public static SessionFactory crearSesion() {
    try {
        registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("/Configuracion/hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();           
    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        System.out.println("Hibernate Configuration problem : " + exception);
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void cerrarsesion() {
    sessionFactory.close();
    String mensaje = "La conexion a la  base de datos ha terminado";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje);
}
```

}
Pais xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated 04-feb-2020 20:03:32 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Clase.Pais" table="pais" catalog="newmundo" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="nombre" type="string">
            <column name="Nombre" length="20" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="continente" class="Clase.Continente" fetch="select">
            <column name="IdContinente" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="millonesHabitantes" type="double">
            <column name="Millones_habitantes" precision="6" scale="3" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Continente xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated 04-feb-2020 20:03:32 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Clase.Continente" table="continente" catalog="newmundo" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="nombre" type="string">
            <column name="Nombre" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="paises" table="pais" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="IdContinente" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Clase.Pais" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Clase Continente

```
public class Continente implements java.io.Serializable {

private int id;
private String nombre;
private Set paises = new HashSet(0);

public Continente() {
}

public Continente(int id, String nombre) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Continente(int id, String nombre, Set paises) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.paises = paises;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Set getPaises() {
    return this.paises;
}

public void setPaises(Set paises) {
    this.paises = paises;
}
```

}

Clase Pais

```
public class Pais  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private String nombre;
 private Continente continente;
 private double millonesHabitantes;

public Pais() {
}

public Pais(String nombre, Continente continente, double millonesHabitantes) {
   this.nombre = nombre;
   this.continente = continente;
   this.millonesHabitantes = millonesHabitantes;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public Continente getContinente() {
    return this.continente;
}

public void setContinente(Continente continente) {
    this.continente = continente;
}
public double getMillonesHabitantes() {
    return this.millonesHabitantes;
}

public void setMillonesHabitantes(double millonesHabitantes) {
    this.millonesHabitantes = millonesHabitantes;
}
```

Foto de la librerias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo error, tras darle vueltas, descubrí que el proyecto estaba guardado en una ruta bastante larga. 
Es decir, en mi caso:

D:\FPGS Desarollo de apliciones multiplataforma\FPGS DAM 3º\Acceso a datos\UD3 - Mapeo objeto relacional\NombreProyecto

Lo solucioné moviendo el proyecto a otra ruta, en este caso utilice la de por defecto: 
D:\Documentos\NetbeansProyects\NombreProyecto

Como ves, este problema me tubo dando vueltas y buscando en foros.. ya que NetBeans no indica este problema, simplemente que la clase no está mapeada.

Desde entonces para NetBeans utilizo la carpeta por defecto o alguna con una ruta corta. Cuando lo acabo lo muevo a otro directorio si lo deseo. 
Suerte!